# Security check an User to a access controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello guys I have a MVC actions that have Authorize attribute set on them. For each one of these actions there is a password/ security pin which is only valid for that Action.

```
public ActionResult Action_1()// generic pin 1
{
Return RedirectToAction("PinCheck", new { returnUrl = "Action_1" });
...
}
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Action_2()// generic pin 2
{
...
}

[Authorize]
public ActionResult PinCheck(string returnUrl)// generic pin 1
{
// request three characters of the pin in random.
...
}
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PinCheck(string a, string b, string c, string returnUrl)// generic pin 1
{
// check the three chars.
...
// How do I store pin check for the controller was a success and don't ask the user unless he closes browser or logout
}
```

My plan of action is checking pins stored by the Admin for the particular User for that particular Action in the Database. So far I have achieved checking `PinCheck()` routine but the problem I face is that the User has to enter the pin every time he requests that particular action. I made a way around this by saving an encrypted cookie on `PinCheck` success. But is there a way to modify the `Authorize` attribute and the Authentication cookie itself to achieve What I am doing?

Answer (score 1):

You can also represent each Pin verified as a claim stored as part of the ClaimsIdentity in the cookie so that you can just query against the user's claims looking for the appropriate PinClaim in each Action.  If you are using the ASP.NET Identity, you can do something like so when you verify the pin:

```
await manager.AddClaimAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), new Claim("<mypinclaim>", "<value>"))
await SignInAsync() // And then resign the user in to regenerate the cookie with the claim
```

Answer (score 0):

One ways of doing this is by creating a custom role provider. You could create one by inheriting from `RoleProvider`. Then override `IsUserInRole` and optionally `FindUsersInRole`, `GetAllRoles`, `GetUsersInRole` to reflect your pin management logic.
Once done, register the custom role provide via the web.config.

A good article on custom role providers (http://bojanskr.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/custom-role-provider.html)